I encountered an issue while running a migration in my Node.js backend project using db-migrate
I attempted to run database migrations in my Node.js backend project using PostgreSQL, but encountered an error despite configuring the database.json file well. The specific error message is: "[ERROR] TypeError: con.connect is not a function."

{
  "dev": {
    "driver": "pg",
    "connection": {
      "host": "localhost",
      "database": "reft",
      "user": "reftreft",
      "password": "reftreft"
    }
  },
  
  "test": {
    "driver": "pg",
    "connection": {
      "host": "localhost",
      "database": "test_reft",
      "user": "reftreft",
      "password": "reftreft"
    }
  }

}

this is my database.json file

